# What does "the third wall is already down" mean in this context? (flirting)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

All explanations I can find is about actors. But what is the meaning in this case?

> “People like me.” She looked down her adorable nose at him. “Most of
> the time.”
> He snorted. “Yeah, I can see that. Flirt.”
> She gasped. Then shrugged. “Yeah.” A couple of seconds ticked past. “You didn’t
> let me flirt with you. And then I thought you were married. My whole
> pattern got thrown off, I and now I don’t know how to act. Trying to
> flirt again seems pointless.”
> The hell it was.    “Try it.”
> “No.
> I can’t!” she sputtered. “**The third wall is already down.”**
> Was
> he sweating under his clothes? What the hell was wrong with him? “What
> is the next stage after flirting? Once you’ve settled in?”

Tessa Bailey "It Happened One Summer"

Comment: Have you Googled "the third wall"?

Comment: As I said, everything in google directs me to: "
1. The imaginary barrier that is considered to separate the audience from the characters in a play or other live performance" or "Breaking the third wall refers to when a character addresses the medium in which they are situated. This is one level removed from breaking the fourth wall, in which characters acknowledge and/or speak to the audience." And I don't understant how it fits in the text, which I'm reading.

Comment: They are actors, and at this time, they are acting. They are breaking the third wall by talking about the acting they are doing.

Comment: The expression is "break the *fourth* wall" ([1807](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fourth+wall)) and perhaps that's what Tessa Bailey meant to say. This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break%20the%20third%20wall%2Cbreak%20the%20fourth%20wall&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) illustrates the usage of the two phrases. That definition you've found, and other examples I've found, of "break the third wall," may be inventions or mistakes by the writer. (And maybe a novel with, "She looked down her adorable nose at him" won't be too careful!)

Comment: @Michael Harvey How does that work? Where would a third wall be? In the wings?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian "Breaking the third wall" derives from different from "breaking the fourth wall", but is not the same thing. The definition the OP gives above makes the distinction clear.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - see below.

Answer (score 1):

The *third* wall is a more recently discussed concept than the fourth. Both are examples of breaking the convention that what the audience sees and hears in a dramatic performance (TV, film, stage, radio drama, etc) are not the actors themselves, but the characters they are playing.

The more established term, the 'fourth wall' refers to an imaginary invisible wall considered to exist between the stage in a theatre and the audience. The other three 'walls' are the back and sides. An example of an actor 'breaking' this would be if they turned to the audience and said 'Macduff will kill Macbeth in a minute'. The audience will be jolted back into reality and be reminded that they are watching a play. There may be artistic reasons for doing this and the device has been employed in a number of TV, film, and stage productions.

More recently, the idea of a 'third' wall has been employed, although the technique is fairly old. It is less concretely derived, since theatrical stages already have three 'walls', but the significance is that *four is one less than three*. The assault on the audience's disbelief is less complete. Here, the discussion of, or reference to, the medium is confined to the actors themselves.. Breaking the third wall does not acknowledge the audience but it can become an 'inside joke' for them to share.

> Examples of Breaking the Third Wall
>
> A character in a horror film saying, “We can’t split up– what, are you
> in a horror movie or something?”
>
> Two characters fall in love in a rom-com and one says, “It’s like the
> perfect ending to a rom-com.”
>
> A character on a TV show saying, “Hm, I think that was last episode.”

[Breaking the Third Wall (StudioBinder)](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/breaking-the-third-wall-definition/)

Comment: You know, it's so funny this. I have done theater [tre, :)) for ages, and I don't buy this as anything other than a Hollywood booboo trying to rectify itself. When actors talk to the audience, that's an "aside".

Comment: @Lambie - well, yes, but everything's 'meta' these days so it's got to have a fancy name. I went to see Othello at the Bristol Old Vic around 1972 and Gerald Harper was in the title role. He was having a lot of fun with the people in the front rows. My girlfriend was positive he was flirting with her.

Comment: @Lambie I'm sure I saw a cartoon where a character was being chased and produced a black crayon, drew the outline of a cave on a nearby mountain, filled it in, and ran into it, evading capture.

Comment: Re the fourth wall, it is just invisible. There was never a question about "breaking it". It's classical 19th c. theatre. Re your cartoon caper, sure. But how is that a "third wall"? :)

Comment: @Lambie - Well, according to the definition, the cartoon character is explicitly acknowledging that it is in a drawn medium, by itself drawing an escape route.

Comment: Maybe I mean if Macduff says "Macbeth is having a bad hair day, the poor darling".

Comment: Yes, I get the guy drawing his own escape route. How is that a third anything?

Comment: @Lambie -  well, instead of being a daffy bird, or whatever, in a daffy-bird world, he is saying 'this is a cartoon'. You don't need to over think this.

Comment: I agree everything has to have a fancy name but your first paragraph seems to describe exactly what happens in a soliloquy! We've _always_ enjoyed actors speaking out-of-character. Even In [1425-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Castle_of_Perseverance) the actor who's been playing God says, "Thus endyth oure gamys!" In panto actors have _always_ grumbled about the gig. **We** might call this breaking the nth wall, but they didn't! People inventing a _3rd_ wall are like the kids who visit the S.E.Music site to say they've invented a new scale/mode/rhythm etc. It's just lack of experience.

Comment: Wouldn't 'self-referential' do, as a description of those examples? Or cute?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - maybe I wasn't clear enough. It would be breaking the third wall if Macduff said to Macbeth, 'I hope you get a good review in the _Guardian_ tomorrow, darling', and it would break the fourth wall if he turned to the audience and said 'What do you think, folks?'

Comment: @Michael Harvey: I'll drop this soon :) Both your Macbeth examples would, I think, break the fourth wall, because in both cases it's the actor speaking: not Macduff. The character Macduff can't say those lines without becoming the actor. And that's true of all the StudioBinder examples, which begin "A character says..." It's _no longer_ the character speaking: it's the actor. It ain't Brecht, but I think the principle's the same. It probably doesn't matter. Frayn's Copenhagen - there's a note on its style [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_(play)#Style)_ - breaks _everything!_

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I heard the Frayn on BBC Radio 4 - brilliant. Have you heard the Tom Stoppard 15 minute piece that he did for Radio 4, 'On Dover Beach', especially for Alan Howard? 'Matthew Arnold engages in animated internal debate with himself about his poem _Dover Beach_ and its place in history'. Very good, and it finishes with a wonderful reading of the poem. It's not on BBC iPlayer now, which is a shame.

Comment: I saw the film of Copenhagen on BBC4 long ago. Yes - brilliant! Would _love_ to hear the Dover Beach thing. (I found a New Statesman review of it but no trace of a recording, sadly.) He writes great one-liners, eh? The ferryman in Shaxp in Love, turning round and telling Will, "I 'ad that Christopher Marlowe in the back once” only breaks the fourth wall - back on topic! - if you know London cabbies!!

Comment: "That's not criticism: it's oceanography." Excellent! Reminds me of the professor in Jumpers. Tvm, Michael. I STILL like the poem!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - v. glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

"Breaking the third wall" means when characters in a production show awareness of the fact that they are characters in a production.

The much more common expression "breaking the fourth wall" refers to an imaginary fourth wall in a theatre that separates the audience from the characters on stage. A character is said to "break" this wall if, as part of the show, they directly address the audience.

There is no "third wall", but the expression "breaking the third wall" is used because a character *showing awareness* of the fact they're in a production is comparable to breaking the fourth wall, but not as severe. A character breaking the fourth wall shows awareness of the world beyond their reality AND communicates to the audience in it. A character breaking the third wall merely shows awareness and does not communicate through it.

Comment: The **invisible fourth wall** just refers to the classical 18th c. stage, which is shaped like a box so that you are looking into, say, to someone's living room or house or other space. When characters address the audience, that is actually called an "aside" in theater parlance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as it is absolutely clear, that theatre has nothing to do with this episode, it seems to me, that Piper simply has in mind, that she's like an open card now. Brendan knows too much about her. That is why the flirting is impossible.